# Tumblr-like Post Types for WordPress

Tags: posts, post-formats, tumblr

Is there any way to get Tumblr-like post types for WordPress? Ones where when you select a post type, it gives you different fields in the post editor for that type. For instance, if there was a link post type, I could enter the URL, the title, and an optional description of the link. Or, for a photo, I could enter a title, browse for the photo, and enter an optional description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex King made a plugin that creates a different admin UI for each Post Format type.

More info here: http://alexking.org/blog/2011/10/25/wordpress-post-formats-admin-ui

Answer (score 0):

The feature has now been rolled into 3.3.1, but I think it still needs some work to be as frictionless like tumblr.